# can diablo 3 be run through wine on linux?

Tags: game-engine, wine

If there's a howto link or similar ill accept that right away - im desperate for running it with my stationary tux box instead of a less capeable laptop.

Comment: This is a programmers' Q&A, try  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to check the WineHQ page for Diablo III: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25953

It appears to install and run correctly. There are a number of issues that have been reported, like with many other Windows games. It looks like it would run best on Ubuntu.